# inconsistent number?

Tags: countable-nouns

From https://www.nytimes.com/2020/08/07/health/coronavirus-exams-mcat.html

"One student said each time examinees entered or exited the test room during the nearly six-hour test, they were required to place their hands on a scanner and then remove their mask — touching their face — so that a photo could be taken for identification purposes."

Why using plural "their hands",but singular,"their mask",and "their face"?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People have two hands so "hands" is plural, but only one face and only one mask, so mask and face are singular.

Note that this is the "singular they" used to mean "he or she".  It means "one person (of unknown gender) but is grammatically plural, and takes a plural verb (they *are*)

Comment: Note that a plural they would also have been valid in this context since there were multiple examinees, but the singular mask, face and photo is how you can tell the author didn’t do that.